# set div height; inner span text centering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so, when I assign a height to either the grid-cart-message or the messages-cart-view sections the inner span text does not center accordingly.  It is cut off within the div.  Any possible way to overcome this?  Thx.

```css
    .grid-cart-message {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #05b1eb;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .grid-cart-message #messages-cart-view .error-msg span, .grid-cart-message #messages-cart-view .success-msg span {
        color: #fff;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 1em 0 1em 1em;
        text-shadow: 0 -0.1em #666;
    }
    .grid-cart-message #messages-cart-view {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 1%;
        width: 98%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class = "grid-cart-message">
     <div class="grid-max">
      <div id="messages-cart-view">
       <ul class="messages">
        <li class="success-msg">
         <ul>
          <li>
           <span>Here is some text that is dynamically assigned.</span>
          </li>
         </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what you want the `<span>`to do

Comment: @sanojlawrence  Its just a message that is displayed to the user, however, the containing division is too big on the current page.  I'd like to make it smaller.  When I scale down this div, the span does not center and is 'clipped'.

Comment: check out my answer bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### try this

**since you added `margin` you faced that problem**

```css
.grid-cart-message {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #05b1eb;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .grid-cart-message #messages-cart-view .error-msg span, .grid-cart-message #messages-cart-view .success-msg span {
        color: #fff;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        font-weight: bold;
        
        text-shadow: 0 -0.1em #666;
    }
    .grid-cart-message #messages-cart-view {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 1%;
        width: 98%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class = "grid-cart-message">
     <div class="grid-max">
      <div id="messages-cart-view">
       <ul class="messages">
        <li class="success-msg">
         <ul>
          <li>
           <span>Here is some text that is dynamically assigned.</span>
          </li>
         </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I could kiss you sanoj.

Answer (score 1):

Also text-centering try this:

```css
.grid-cart-message {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #05b1eb;
  overflow: hidden;
}
    
.grid-cart-message #messages-cart-view .error-msg span, .grid-cart-message #messages-cart-view .success-msg span {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 -0.1em #666;
}
.grid-cart-message #messages-cart-view {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1%;
  width: 98%;
}
.list {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class = "grid-cart-message">
     <div class="grid-max">
      <div id="messages-cart-view">
       <ul class="messages">
        <li class="success-msg">
         <ul>
          <li class="list">
           <span>Here is some text that is dynamically assigned.</span>
          </li>
         </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why do you get two dots there, and how ? since O.P uses `<li>` you should not make text center it of no use

Comment: It's on default code, I didn't add. Your code has also these 2 dots. http://i.imgur.com/6qYl6rj.png

Comment: @ibrahim yea trying to remove